# Turn off Global XSS Filtering for spec. controller?

Tags: php, apache, facebook, codeigniter

I'm developing project integrated with FB and I have problem with Deautharization (when user remove App from his Authorized Apps)

Old Question: CodeIgniter => Facebook App Deauthorization

Edit2: I just realized the problem....

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global XSS Filtering
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
| COOKIE data is encountered
|
*/
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

CodeIgniter block POST requests that don't have specific token as hidden value...

So question now is : can I turn it off for specific controller ?

Comment: What do you mean by `$ip` here? the user ip? please note that **Facebook** calls this URL and not the **user** himself!

Comment: Yes, but that is just check. And yes $ip is client's IP.

Comment: @CappY: As I said, you won't be getting the user IP also just extract the Facebook user Id from that call and put it in the log

Comment: I still don't need UID. For now I'm just checking when FB call this URL will it log it as successful call.

Comment: Are you sure there's no fatal error, or something like that? Maybe you want to check your PHP error log.

Comment: Also check your routes configurations, try removing the `$ip` variable and put a dummy text and then remove the application (just to test the link)...etc

Comment: @silent,@ifaour - I'm sure that there is no fatal error. When I call same URL from browser (GET request.no POST), It's allright

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable `global_xss_filtering` selectively using this guide: [Codeigniter - Disable XSS filtering on a post basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788476/codeigniter-disable-xss-filtering-on-a-post-basis)