# Some markup mysteriously goes missing when send to server using ajax (POST) as string

Tags: php, jquery, post, codeigniter-2

> **OS:** Windows 7 (64-Bit)
> **WAMP Version:** 2.2
> **Apache Version:** 2.2.22
> **PHP
>   Version:** 5.4.3
> **Framework:** CodeIgniter 2.1.2

Hi, I am experiencing something strange, and can't seem to pinpoint the cause. I am sending a js object to server to be saved in db in BLOB. The object is converted to JSON string using `JSON.stringify()` before sending it in Ajax(POST) call.

**Object After Using `JSON.stringify`**

```
[{"page_id":"1","site_id":456,"composite_id":"456-1-text-1","type":"2","properties":"{\"id\":\"text-1\",\"isModified\":false,\"isNew\":false,\"name\":\"Text 1\",\"content\":\"<span style=\\\"text-decoration:underline;font-size:x-large;color:#7092be;background-color:#c8bfe7;\\\"><strong>Your text here</strong></span>\",\"keywords\":\"\",\"top\":103,\"left\":119,\"width\":130,\"height\":30,\"style\":{\"borderColor\":\"#1e07da\",\"borderSize\":\"2\",\"borderRadius\":\"6\",\"shadowType\":\"drop-shadow\",\"shadowColor\":\"#000000\",\"shadowSize\":\"0\",\"shadowBlur\":\"0\",\"boxShadowColor\":\"#000000\",\"boxShadowPosX\":\"3\",\"boxShadowPosY\":\"2\",\"boxShadowBlur\":\"5\",\"boxShadowType\":\"\",\"zIndex\":2020}}"}]
```

This is the concerning part from above string that gets modified(Key-Value Pair):

```
\"content\":\"<span style=\\\"text-decoration:underline;font-size:x-large;color:#7092be;background-color:#c8bfe7;\\\"><strong>Your text here</strong></span>\"
```

I send this string to api controller using ajax. When I receive it in the controller I use `print_r()` to print the variable. But now insted of the above mentioned part this is what I receive:

```
[{"page_id":"1","site_id":456,"composite_id":"456-1-text-1","type":"2","properties":"{\"id\":\"text-1\",\"isModified\":false,\"isNew\":false,\"name\":\"Text 1\",\"content\":\"<span ><strong><em>Your text here</em></strong></span>\",\"keywords\":\"\",\"top\":103,\"left\":119,\"width\":130,\"height\":30,\"style\":{\"borderColor\":\"#1e07da\",\"borderSize\":\"2\",\"borderRadius\":\"6\",\"shadowType\":\"drop-shadow\",\"shadowColor\":\"#000000\",\"shadowSize\":\"0\",\"shadowBlur\":\"0\",\"boxShadowColor\":\"#000000\",\"boxShadowPosX\":\"3\",\"boxShadowPosY\":\"2\",\"boxShadowBlur\":\"5\",\"boxShadowType\":\"\",\"zIndex\":2020}}"}]
```

As you can see the concerned part is missing the style settings and is now modified to:

```
\"content\":\"<span ><strong><em>Your text here</em></strong></span>\"
```

I have been searching it over the internet, but it does not seem to be a common problem as I cant find anything related to it. So now I am counting on SO.

Regards

**UPDATE:**

I used `var_dump($_REQUEST)`as suggested by @BogdanBurim. And this is the concerned part:

```
\&quot;content\&quot;:\&quot;&lt;span style=\\\&quot;text-decoration:underline;font-size:x-large;color:#7092be;background-color:#c8bfe7;\\\&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Your text here&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\&quot;
```

As you can see the style settings are still there. So with we come to the decision that CI filters might be removing this part from string. So now the question is how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is that part which is missing the style settings coming through some filers? Try var_dump($_REQUEST) in index.php, see if input is OK there. If ok, it is CI filters problem. Other way some server settings.

Comment: @BogdanBurim Thanks. So it seems it is a problem with CI filter. I used `var_dump` and the style settings are there (updated the description). So now the question becomes how to avoid this?

Comment: The problem is that we do not know what filters did you enable.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224873/turn-off-global-xss-filtering-for-spec-controller

Comment: @BogdanBurim Interesting approach. But my concern is that the markup that is being sent in the request is handled by users. And the database contains some critical information. Even if I avoid XSS filtering selectively, it still can be dangerous as someone might use it for sql injection. I was thinking if I can send and save this data encoded as binary. And decode it on client side once I receive it back. Does this seem a viable approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well after discussion with @BogdanBurim, I came to conclusion that to avoid XSS to some extent CI removed any text included within quotes and double quotes, from data sent to server.

There was an option to extend CI_Input library to allow selective disabling of XSS filter. That would solve my issue but would raise security concerns. So instead what I did is I encode (base_64) the data before sending it to the api. It is saved in DB as BLOB. And when fetched is decoded on client side.