# Codeigniter removes HTML entities

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, html-entities

I have a form in codeigniter to save some html content to the database. 
Example this HTML:

```
<div style="width:400px">
  <div style="background-color:yellow">
    Header
  </div>
</div>
```

When i save it i get the html tags broken. Even if i "print_r" the $_POST on submitting the form i see the html tags broken.
Here is what i get:

```
<div 
  <div 
    Header
  </div>
</div>
```

But the same form without codeigniter (simple code) works normal and shows proper html.

Is this normal in CI? How can this be solved?

Comment: I don't see any problem with that, unless we are missing some processes here. Care to provide a lot 'more' detail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a XSS filtering problem. On your CI installation, you have set the global_xss_filtering flag to true, therefore it cleanses all the input data before you can use it. here, the problem is described and solved before:

[Codeigniter - Disable XSS filtering on a post basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788476/codeigniter-disable-xss-filtering-on-a-post-basis)

and here it is described in the "Security Filtering" section:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to put "/" at style closing :

```
<div style="width:400px;">
    <div style="background-color:yellow;">
       Header
    </div>
</div>
```