# Codeigniter - Remove xss_clean on a specific field

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss

I have configured the `config.php` with:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

But I need to disable xss_clean for a specific `post` parameter. Is there anyway to add exception to this global setting. This will also reduce me space and time for providing `$data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);` in all methods except the one I dont need.

Comment: look at the thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788476/codeigniter-disable-xss-filtering-on-a-post-basis

Answer (score 6):

please use

```
    $this->input->post('name',false);
```

second parameter accepts whether to perform xss_clean or not

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried `var_dump($this->input->post('name',FALSE))` and also `var_dump($_POST['name'])` even at the beginning of the controller, both printing the string after xss_clean. I am losing some data in this process.

Comment: @Saravanan any specific type of data ? like `html tags` or `special characters` ?

Comment: Its an URL, `http://sub.example.com:8080/controller/method?text=TEXT%20SECOND&destination=1234567890` is what i enter in textarea. The post variable contains `http //sub.example.com:8080/controller/method?text=TEXT SECOND&destinati` at `var_dump($this->input->post('name',FALSE));`

Comment: for get parameter use $this->input->get('name',false);                                      if still not works turn off global xss clean to off and manually perform xss clean operation where you require using the second argument set to true for xss_clean and false to get input as is...