# PHP Codeigniter bypass html_scape function

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-escape-characters

I am running a php codeigniter app, and I need to bypass the `html_escape` function to insert embeded html code into the database.

This is an example of what I need to insert into the DB:

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8' scr='https://www.buzzsprout.com/423805.js?container_id=buzzsprout-small-player-423805&player=small'></script>
```

I've tried

```
$data['url'] = $this->input->post('podcast_url');
```

But it keeps inserting `[removed][removed]` to the DB. If I use just the link, it works fine.

Is there a way to bypass that?

Comment: I am not sure to have understand your problem.
I suppose you have to write "<script type..etc.etc." into a DB field and in your field you find "[removed][removed]" (?).. Please, try to do a print('<pre>'); print_r($data['url']); print('</pre>'); die(); and tell us what you find here. The problem can be the manipulation of string before, in post, or in automatically escape into CI DB functions. Please give us also the code you use to insert/update your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Change the configuration in `application/config/config.php` to

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

[Reference](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html?highlight=xss#id3)

Related question :- [Codeigniter - Disable XSS filtering on a post basis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3788476/12731030)